# Exclude multiple cells from range

Tags: excel, vba, range

My question is how can I remove a cell or cells from a range object? I asked something very similar earlier and some people pointed me to this question: [Remove cell from Range (object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103551/remove-cell-from-range-object)

**Accepted answer:**

```
Function getExcluded(ByVal rngMain As Range, rngExc As Range) As Range
    Dim rngTemp     As Range
    Dim rng         As Range

    Set rngTemp = rngMain
    Set rngMain = Nothing

    For Each rng In rngTemp
        If rng.Address <> rngExc.Address Then
            If rngMain Is Nothing Then
                Set rngMain = rng
            Else
                Set rngMain = Union(rngMain, rng)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set getExcluded = rngMain
End Function


Sub test()
    MsgBox getExcluded(Range("A1:M10000"), Range("a10")).Address
End Sub
```

The accepted answer only works if the excluded range is a single cell - at least that's how it was for me when I tried it. My cells to be excluded have usually more than one cell, so I tried to adapt the code:

**My try:**

```
Function getExcluded(ByVal rngMain As Range, rngExcl As Range) As Range
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Dim cellTemp As Range, cellExcl As Range

    Set rngTemp = rngMain
    Set rngMain = Nothing

    For Each cellTemp In rngTemp 'go through all cells in established range
        If Intersect(cellTemp, rngExcl) Is Nothing Then 'check for each cell if it intersects with the range to be excluded; no overlap -> put it into rngMain
            If rngMain Is Nothing Then
                Set rngMain = cellTemp
            Else
                rngMain = Union(rngMain, cellTemp)
            End If

            Debug.Print "cellTemp: " & cellTemp.Address
            Debug.Print "rngMain: " & rngMain.Address

        End If
    Next cellTemp

    Set getExcluded = rngMain


Sub test5()

    getExcluded(Range("A1:D3"), Range("B1:C1")).Select
End Sub
```

The problem seems to occur in the line `Set rngMain = Union(rngMain, rng)`. My `Debug.Print` statements tell me that `cellTemp` is being iterated through as it should; however, even though the line with `Union` gets executed and no matter what `cellTemp` is, `rngMain` stays `$A$1`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @FaneDuru New question, a bit different from the last. Idk if your code snippet is applicable, but I'd be interested if it is

Comment: You're missing a `set`. Wonder why it doesn't error...

Comment: `rngMain = Union(rngMain, cellTemp)`

Comment: @SJR So the code is fine except for the missing `set`? I mean it's working now, thank you for that! Curious that I didn't get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @Nathan_Sav.

This will allow the addition of many exclude ranges:

```
Function testexclude(rngMain As Range, ParamArray rngExclude() As Variant) As Range


Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(rngExclude, 1) To UBound(rngExclude, 1)
    Dim rngexcluderng As Range
    If rngexcluderng Is Nothing Then
        Set rngexcluderng = rngExclude(i)
    Else
        Set rngexcluderng = Union(rngexcluderng, rngExclude(i))
    End If
Next i


Dim c As Range
For Each c In rngMain

    If Intersect(c, rngexcluderng) Is Nothing Then
        Dim r As Range
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Set r = c
        Else
            Set r = Union(r, c)
        End If
    End If

Next c

Set testexclude = r

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like so, setting the union range also

```
Function testexclude(rngMain As Excel.Range, rngExclude As Excel.Range) As Excel.Range

Dim c As Excel.Range
Dim r As Excel.Range

For Each c In rngMain

    If Intersect(c, rngExclude) Is Nothing Then
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Set r = c
        Else
            Set r = Union(r, c)
        End If
    End If

Next c

Set testexclude = r

End Function
```