# How to find the missing value from two array

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

RANGE.A2 = {1,2,3,4} and B2 = {1,2,4,5}
From above two ranges i need to result like (Missing) C2 = {3} and (mismatch) D2 = {5},Any Formula or VBA code Availble means please share

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328551/non-intersect-range-vba  You are interested in finding the complement of the intersection elements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.