# Given 2 named ranges, set operations in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

Let's suppose that you are considering 2 named ranges, A and B.

In VBA Excel, are there built in functions to ask questions like:

1. Is one range entirely contained in another?
2. If the 2 named ranges are not mutually exclusive, what is the range that is inside A but not B, vice versa?

Basically, set operations related functionality....

Comment: You have Intersect and Union, but that's it OOB

Comment: see also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328551/non-intersect-range-vba

Comment: @Tim Williams I think you have answered the OP's two questions exhaustively and should therefore post your answer as an answer because otherwise this thread will get closed which wouldn't do justice to either you or the question.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box you have `Application.Union` and `.Intersect`, which do more or less what you'd expect when provided two ranges.

For anything else you will need to code something up, or search for something someone has already provided, such as the "Difference" post here - [Non-Intersect Range VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328551/non-intersect-range-vba)